# How to use threading so time.sleep() doesn't stop all script?

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading, robotics

I started learning python 3 months ago and I wanted to start by building a robot, today I controlled the servo motor using a library the robot company made for its specific motor Hat, my issue is when the servo motor turns smoothly from the middle to the right or left using a for loop (this is for steering the robot), I use `time.sleep()`, however when I sleep all other functions in the robot are temporarily stopped.

I searched this issue and found out I need to use something called threading, I learned very very basic threading but I still don't know how to implement it in this code.

```
# Importing libraries
from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller,Event
import Adafruit_PCA9685
import threading
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


# Defining a function to set up the servo motors to a frequency of 50Hz
def setup_servos(frequency):
    global head_right_left,head_up_down,steering

    head_right_left=Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
    head_up_down=Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
    steering=Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()


    head_right_left.set_pwm_freq(frequency)
    head_up_down.set_pwm_freq(frequency)
    steering.set_pwm_freq(frequency)


# Defining functions for turning the head
def head_right():
    head_right_left.set_pwm(1,0,170)
def head_left():
    head_right_left.set_pwm(1,0,450)
def head_up():
    head_up_down.set_pwm(0,0,470)
def head_down():
    head_up_down.set_pwm(0,0,260)
def head_neutral():
    head_right_left.set_pwm(1,0,320)
    head_up_down.set_pwm(0,0,320)


# Defining functions to steer the wheels
def turn_right():
    for x in range(320,220,-1):
            steering.set_pwm(2,0,x)
            time.sleep(0.008)


def turn_left():
    for x in range(320,420):
        steering.set_pwm(2,0,x)
        time.sleep(0.008)


# Defining a function to setup the GPIO pins for the dc motor
def setup_dc_motor():
    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)


# Defining a function that will stop the motors -------> OUTPUT=0
def stop_motor():
    GPIO.output(17,0)
    GPIO.output(27,0)
    GPIO.output(18,0)


# Defining a function that will drive the robot forwards
def drive_forwards():
    GPIO.output(27,0)
    GPIO.output(18,1)
    dc_motor_pwm.start(100)


# Defining a function that will drive the robot backwards
def drive_backwards():
    GPIO.output(27,1)
    GPIO.output(18,0)
    dc_motor_pwm.start(100)


# Defining a function that will stop the robot -----> PWM=0
def stop_robot():
    dc_motor_pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(0)


# This class is used for fixing the button mapping on the PS4 controller
class MyEventDefinition(Event):

    def x_pressed(self):
        return self.button_id == 0 and self.button_type == 1 and self.value == 1
    def x_released(self):
        return self.button_id == 0 and self.button_type == 1 and self.value == 0


    def circle_pressed(self):
        return self.button_id == 1 and self.button_type == 1 and self.value == 1
    def circle_released(self):
        return self.button_id == 1 and self.button_type == 1 and self.value == 0


    def square_pressed(self):
        return self.button_id == 3 and self.button_type == 1 and self.value == 1
    def square_released(self):
        return self.button_id == 3 and self.button_type == 1 and self.value == 0


    def triangle_pressed(self):
        return self.button_id == 2 and self.button_type == 1 and self.value == 1
    def triangle_released(self):
        return self.button_id == 2 and self.button_type == 1 and self.value == 0


# This class provides methods when a button is pressed
class MyController(Controller):
    """"""

    def on_R3_right(self,value=30000):
        head_right()


    def on_R3_left(self,value=-30000):
        head_left()


    def on_R3_up(self,value=-30000):
        head_up()


    def on_R3_down(self,value=30000):
        head_down()


    def on_R3_at_rest(self):
        head_neutral()


    def on_R2_press(self,value=25000):
        drive_forwards()


    def on_L2_press(self,value=25000):
        drive_backwards()


    def on_R2_release(self):
        stop_robot()


    def on_L2_release(self):
        stop_robot()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_left_arrow_press(self):
        turn_left()


    def on_right_arrow_press(self):  #-------------------> RIGHT HERE I NEED HELP
        turn_right()





    def on_left_right_arrow_release(self):
        steering.set_pwm(2,0,320)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------



# The actual code

setup_servos(50)


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

setup_dc_motor()

stop_motor()

dc_motor_pwm=GPIO.PWM(17,1000)
dc_motor_pwm.start(0)



controller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv=False, event_definition=MyEventDefinition)
controller.listen(timeout=60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask why do you need the sleep in the first place? Why do you need to delay your robot?
You can call sleep in a thread (Which in most python implementations is not an actual thread [Refer to Python's GIL]) but you will need to move other parts of your code to the thread so the sleep will actually do something useful.

Comment: i need the sleep so the car's wheels turn slowly when steering it, oh and can you show me how to use threading in this code if you know how to

Comment: @HamzaEyad In that case you would probably want to start a thread that handles each movement direction. you might also want to add a mutex later to prevent an attempt to move to different directions concurrently (And maybe its fine for you).

```Python
import threading

move_thread = threading.Thread(target=your_function, args=(args, for, the, function))
move_thread.start()
```

Comment: Alright thanks I realised I need to use multiprocessing and not threading thanks so much dude ur the best